# updating mutable array in table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I'm a newbie for iOS. I have a problem about `NSMutableArray`. Hope you will help me

My app has 2 view controllers (Home and List).

In List , I have a `NSMutableArray`

```
self.arrayCategory = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5,@"6", nil]];
```

and it put in View did load. I use

```
[self.arrayCategory insertObject:self.textfield.text atIndex:1];
```

to add objects to `arrayCategory`. It only works if I am in List View Controller. It does not work when I back to Home then go to List again. It only display a array has 6 elements. Can you please help me to find out solution. Sorry for my bad english. Thanks all

Comment: Your list view controller probably gets created every time you go there from home, and creates a new copy of `arrayCategory`.

Comment: You want to pass the data from one controller to another? Or save it to disk / user defaults?

Comment: @BlackRider: Can you please explain more about this? If can, can you please comment your solution so that I can understand clearly more about it. thank you very much

Comment: @Wain: No. Example: in List, I have an array and it has 6 elements. I add 2 elements to this array. I will have 8 elements. This is ok. However, if back to Home then go to List again. It only display 6 elements instead of 8 elements. I use table view to display array.

Comment: I understand the situation, but how do you want to resolve it? By saving the list? Or by passing the modified list to another controller? Does Home have any requirement to use the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you recreate arrayCategory your when entering home screen. You can check it by adding logging

```
NSLog(@"Here I am creating/recreating arrayCategory");
```

also just to test (!) you can try to replace

```
self.arrayCategory = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5,@"6", nil]];
```

with

```
static NSMutableArray *staticArray;
if (staticArray == nil) {
    staticArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6", nil];
}
self.arrayCategory = staticArray;
```

in such a case arrayCategory will not be recreated but this solution is not good. It is better to use singleton or try another place to store arrayCategory.

Comment: As Avt says, this is not a good solution and you should decide how you want to store the data and for how long rather than just creating a static

Comment: I never receive upvotes suggesting to newbies solutions with 'static' :(

Comment: @user3525058 if you are satisfied with answer please accept it.